# what is the alternative for bellowing command?

Tags: devops

k get componentstatus
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE                         ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true","reason":""}

Answer (score 0):

```bash
kubectl get --raw '/healthz?verbose'
```

this works for me